# using string values for DATE criterias for COUNTIF in vba excel

Tags: vba, excel, criteria, countif

I have 2 cells in Range B:B, which I wish to apply `countif` formula to via VBA in Excel.

```
27/09/2017
13/06/2018
```

I have tried

```
MsgBox (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B:B"), "27/09/2017"))
```

This returns 0

```
MsgBox (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B:B"), CDate("27/09/2017")))
```

This returns 1

I am trying to figure out how I can get the macro to return both date values, via

```
MsgBox (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B:B"), "<=" & CDate("13/06/2018")))
```

However this returns 0

This seems to indicate that I do not quite understand how to filter dates in countif via strings. Would it be possible to share a alternative?

I hope to implement a text input box where the user can input a date string which then applies the `countif` on

Comment: try the last `MgsBox` with `CDbl(CDate("13/06/2018"))` this compares the actual value of the date independent from the format.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Works like a charm thank you.

Just for learning sake, why does Cdate not work?

If I had opted to use a date value instead of a string input, do I still need to use Cdbl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the date into a double first to compare the actual value of the date independent from the format.

```
 "<=" & CDbl(CDate("13/06/2018"))
```

**Why is this?**
If you concatenate a `string` with a `date` like in `"<=" & CDate("13/06/2018")` the `date` is converted into a `string` and the result is `"<=13/06/2018"` (here the date is a string not a value).

If you convert the `date` into a `double` `CDbl(CDate("13/06/2018")` the result is `43264` which is the serial number that represents the date.
Dates in Excel are stored as serial numbers counting from `1900-01-01` so `2018-06-13` is day `43264` since `1900-01-01`.

So with `"<=" & CDbl(CDate("13/06/2018"))` you actually compare the cell value to `"<=43264"`. So you compare to a value and not a text. This works because if a cell is formatted as `date` Excel actually stores the serial value but shows the formatted string for user compatibility.

**Conclusion**
If you want to compare dates always compare their values not their strings.

Also see: [How to use dates and times in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214094/how-to-use-dates-and-times-in-excel).

Comment: Thanks for this friend, makes alot of sense